# Syntax error sending data to a database

Tags: php, sql, database

I keep getting the following error

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(''),'','','','','')' at line 3

My code can be seen below:

```
//Insert statement into the Users table with the values posted from the form
$sql="INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Forename, Surname, Email, `Post Code`, `Phone Number`)
VALUES
('$_POST[username]', md5.('$_POST[password]'),'$_POST[fore]','$_POST[sur]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[postcode]','$_POST[phone]')";
```

Comment: Can you show us $sql's contents?

Comment: `md5` will be interpreted as string and not a function by PHP

Comment: md5 works on my other PHP files so it might just be the way I have declared it here, also what do you mean by the sql contents? Sorry im new to PHP

Comment: Your code is open to SQL Injection.  Read here how to fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: First, make sure that $_POST is what you think it is. Then follow Johan's advice, which will fix both your md5 issue and any quoting issues you might run into.

Comment: Yeah I understand the security flaws, this is just a small project for my college course, no need to go over the top with security my lecturer said just in this example work

Comment: Then chck the quotes within the $_POST variable too. $_POST[username] is not correct, $_POST['username'] might be.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I needed to md5 my password before the sql statement, silly me! works now anyway, thanks to anyone who tried to help xD

Answer (score 0):

Your Quotes are missed !
this is correct `$_POST[username]` only if **username** is defined like this :

```
define ('username', 'username');
```

Also : `md5()` is a function, and not an object , please refer to the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)

You should try as follow ( don't be affraid to get your code more clear to read)

```
$username   = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username']        : '';
$password   = isset($_POST['password']) ? md5($_POST['password']) : '';
$fore       = isset($_POST['fore'])      ? $_POST['fore']           : '';
$sur        = isset($_POST['sur'])   ? $_POST['sur']            : '';
$email      = isset($_POST['email'])     ? $_POST['email']      : '';
$postcode   = isset($_POST['postcode']) ? $_POST['postcode']        : '';
$phone      = isset($_POST['phone'])     ? $_POST['phone']      : '';


$sql="INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Forename, Surname, Email, `Post Code`, `Phone Number`)
VALUES
('$username', $password'),'$fore','$sur','$email','$postcode','$phone')";
```